# How can I retrieve what permissions I have with my users?

Tags: facebook, stream, publish

How can I retrieve what permissions (eg publish_stream) I have with my users? Because if I want to obtain this authorization is missing only the server but not unnecessarily burden I start by querying every call ..

Answer (score 3):

Call `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` and you'll see them.